# Rails: test mailgun on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, email, mailgun

I have a Rails app running on Heroku that uses Mailgun to process incoming emails. I haven't been able to figure how I can debug my email processing locally (on localhost) instead of having to push everything up to heroku every time I make a change. (this is just a test app - I'm the only one using it)

Is it possible to work with Mailgun locally? If so, how do I go about it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mailgun gives you the option to [store a message for later retrieval](https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#receiving-forwarding-and-storing-messages). If you configure it that way, you'll be able to fetch messages from development for processing without having to set up a publicly-accessible webhook for Mailgun to hit.

But I'm assuming you have production configured with an HTTP endpoint, and it's no fun to do things differently between environments. There are a few tools that will let you set up a public endpoint that routes to `localhost`:

- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which I've used to good effect to [test Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html). You can set up a permanent subdomain so you don't have to constantly change your Mailgun configuration.
- [UltraHook](http://www.ultrahook.com/), which I haven't personally used, but looks the same.
- [Localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/) which looks easiest to start up, but like you get a different host at every boot.

If you have a permanent publicly-accessible server, you can also [maintain your own tunnel](http://www.jayway.com/2013/10/17/tunneling-to-localhost-via-ssh/).

Comment: Thank you @Kristján - it took me about 10 minutes to setup everything with ngrok!

Answer (score 1):

mailgun provides a sandbox that you can use for localhost the only downside to this is that you have to add the test email to valid recipient.

Answer (score 0):

using this gem might be another possible solution:

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/ or https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web for more advanced features

- follow installation from repo
- mail will open in new tab