# Laravel : How can i send Email from the Localhost Mailgun

Tags: email, laravel-5, localhost, mailgun

This question is repeated but I am not receiving emails from Localhost

Production: In production  work perfect

What I tried:

use ngrok as the similar question for Rails
  [Rails: test mailgun on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893881/rails-test-mailgun-on-localhost)

in services.php

**Change Domain**:

```
'domain' => 'sandbox*********.mailgun.org';
```

also as per documentation on locally

```
'domain' => 'samples.mailgun.org'
```

the other configuration seems to be perfect Thank, thats why i am 
 receiving email in production
 Thank you for helping

Comment: are you using a free plan on mailgun to test or are you using the same account used on production? And if Free are you using a registered recipient email address?

Comment: yes its a free plan